# Why am I getting an error message?

Tags: php, authentication

I wrote this "log in" page and last night everything worked fine except the error messages did not display. Today, I went to double check my work and I get this error message: Call to undefined function showForm() in E:\wwwroot\teamc\logIn.php on line 7. I did not change or alter my code from last night to this morning. Can anyone see why the error message is now showing up??

```
<?php
session_start();

    //validate text was entered in UserName text box
if(empty($_POST['txtUserName']))
    {
        showForm('Please Enter A User Name.');
        exit();
    }
else
    {
        $UserName = $_POST['txtUserName'];
    }

//validate text was entered in password text box
if(empty($_POST['txtPassword']))
    {
        showForm('Please Enter A Password.');
        exit();
    }
else
    {
        $Password = $_POST['txtPassword'];
    }

if($Password != Password($UserName))
    {
        showForm('User Name And Password Do Not Match!');
        exit();
    }


function Password($UserName)
{
//database login
$dsn = 'mysql:host=XXX;dbname=XXX';
$username='XXX';
$password='XXX';
//variable for errors
$options = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
//try to run code
try {
//object to open database
$db = new PDO($dsn,$username,$password, $options);
//check username against password
    $SQL = $db->prepare("Select USER_PASSWORD FROM user WHERE user_name =  :UserName");
    $SQL->bindValue(':UserName', $UserName);
    $SQL->execute();
    $username = $SQL->fetch();

    if($username === false)
        {
            $password = null;
        }
    else
        {
            $password = $username['USER_PASSWORD'];
            include 'index.php';
        }

    return $password;
    $SQL->closeCursor();
    $db = null;

    } catch(PDOException $e){
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        echo("<p>Database Error: $error_message</p>");
        exit();
    }

}
function showForm($formMessage)
{?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1  /DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>WisCon Log In</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/wiscon-default-styles.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/FormStyle.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/validateLogInForm.js/validateLogInForm.js">  </script>
</head>

<body id="logPage">
<div id="wrapper">

    <?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>
    <?php include('includes/topNavigation.php'); ?>

    <div id="mainContent">

        <div class="formDiv">
            <form name="registerForm" id="registerForm" action="" method="post">
                <h1 style="color:#FF530D; text-align: center">Log into your account here!</h1>

                <fieldset id="security">
                    <legend>Security</legend>
                    <label for="txtUserName" class="boxLabel">User Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="txtUserName" name="txtUserName" autofocus="autofocus" required="required" />
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        if(!("autofocus" in document.createElement("input")))
                        {
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                document.getElementById("txtUserName").focus();
                            }, 10);

                        }
                        </script>
                    <label for="txtPassword" class="boxLabel">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" id="txtPassword" name="txtPassword" required="required" />
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset id="submission">
                    <div id="buttons">
                        <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateLogInForm()"/>
                        <input type="reset" id="btnReset" name="btnReset" >
                    </div><!--end buttons-->
                </fieldset>
</p>
            </form>
        </div><!--end div class=formDiv-->
    </div><!--end div id=mainContent-->

    <?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>

</div><!--end div id=wrapper-->
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `exit()` after calling the function?
Try removing it and see if it works.

Also the reason you are not seeing the error message inside the html code is simply because you are not calling the passed variable `$formMessage` somewhere inside the html output.

Comment: Exit merely kills the PHP script running at that moment.

Comment: Thank you i know it, that's why i said to the OP to remove it.

Comment: Would this work?                    <legend>Security</legend><h2><?php $showForm() ?>
<label for="txtUserName" class="boxLabel">User Name:</label>

Comment: @Hugoriffic your variable inside the function is `$formMessage` not `$showForm()` (a mashup of your function and variable?), and you are missing the `</h2>` closing tag. You could do `<legend>Security</legend><h2><?php echo $formMessage; ?></h2><label for="txtUserName" class="boxLabel">User Name:</label>`

Comment: Ugh!! That is what I meant.

Comment: Everything works now, except, when you first go to the log in page the error message "Please Enter A User Name." is already displaying. Is this due to the fact that I am not hitting the database first??

Answer (score 0):

From the manual [`exit()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)

> Output a message and terminate the current script

So anything after, including where you define the function will not be executed

It is not necessary to use `exit()` in an `if/else` as it will not execute the `else` when the `if` returns `true`.

**Edit**
If the `exit()` in the `if/else`'s are necessary, move your `function showForm($formMessage)` above the if, to prevent it from not being executed / available to call.

**Edit 2**
To make the error message visible try adding something like this -

```
<?php if($formMessage !="") echo "<h2 style=\"color:#FF0000; text-align: center\">".$formMessage."</h2>"; ?>
```

between

```
...
<h1 style="color:#FF530D; text-align: center">Log into your account here!</h1>
<?php if($formMessage !="") echo "<h2 style=\"color:##FF0000; text-align: center\">".$formMessage."</h2>"; ?>
<fieldset id="security">
...
```

Comment: My guess is that the exit was put there to prevent the script from continuing, as you said. Otherwise OP would have to place all the remaining code he wanted to be executed into the else block, which (with indenting and all) degrades readability. Functionally though, it's not incorrect.

Comment: I have tried everything suggested within this thread. I removed the exit within the if/else statements, I have put the showForm function above the if/else statements, I tried adding an else after the password validation and put the Password function within that, I've added the text "Welcome to Wiscon" within the showForm function as a default message and the message "Please Enter A User Name" still displays whenever you first hit the page. I've even removed the words from the showForm function and put null in the place of this and it still shows up. What is going on??